# Amazon Chime(ReactNative): [AppInfo setAppVersionName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281888aa0

Tags: react-native, bridge, amazon-chime

I am facing issue in Amazon Chime, React Native SDK with bridging, It is working fine in Android crash is only in iOS when

```
NativeFunction.startMeeting(meetingResponse.JoinInfo.Meeting.Meeting, meetingResponse.JoinInfo.Attendee.Attendee);
```

was called.
[Crash log in XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctMVp.png)
[Exception in ios device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TcYa.jpg)
Please find the below line of code mentied below where crash is happing.

```
-(void)startAudioVideo
{
   NSError* error = nil;
   BOOL started = [meetingSession.audioVideo startAndReturnError:&error];
   if (started && error == nil)
   {
     [logger infoWithMsg:@"RN meeting session was started successfully"];

     [meetingSession.audioVideo startRemoteVideo];
   }
   else
   {
     NSString *errorMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to start meeting, error: %@", error.description];
     [logger errorWithMsg:errorMsg];
     
     // Handle missing permission error
     if ([error.domain isEqual:@"AmazonChimeSDK.PermissionError"])
     {
       AVAudioSessionRecordPermission permissionStatus = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] recordPermission];
       if (permissionStatus == AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionUndetermined)
       {
         [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted)
         {
           if (granted)
           {
             [logger infoWithMsg:@"Audio permission granted"];
             // Retry after permission is granted
             [self startAudioVideo];
           }
           else
           {
             [logger infoWithMsg:@"Audio permission not granted"];
             [self sendEventWithName:kEventOnMeetingEnd body:nil];
           }
         }];
       }
       else if (permissionStatus == AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionDenied)
       {
         [logger errorWithMsg:@"User did not grant permission, should redirect to Settings"];
         [self sendEventWithName:kEventOnMeetingEnd body:nil];
       }
     }
     else
     {
       // Uncaught error
       [self sendEventWithName:kEventOnError body: errorMsg];
       [self sendEventWithName:kEventOnMeetingEnd body:nil];
     }
   }
}
```

Could you please help me out.

Thanks and Regards, Pawan

[Git hub link for the similar issue](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-android/issues/226)
I have tried that but it is not worked for me.